# How do I get import statements search files within for angular project using sublime?

Tags: angular, import, autocomplete, sublimetext2, auto-import

I generated angular 4 project through CLI and opened in Sublime 3 Text editor.Prior to this I was using VSCode which searched files within the project when I used to type import statements such as below.

```
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
```

However when I use sublime text 3 it does not show any suggestions when I type  import `{  }` from `"./` and hit `ctrl + space`.

Comment: Sublime doesn't do that out of the box, although there may be a package on https://packagecontrol.io that adds that functionality.

Comment: It will be nice if you can tell one package name which would work. I appreciate the time you took to answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 plugins that I know can help you.

1. [FuzzyFilePath](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/FuzzyFilePath).
2. [Auto​File​Name](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AutoFileName).

Search them and download them from Package Control.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for . Thanks for taking time to answer this.

Comment: Glad I could help..!! :)